# Javascript query returning 'undefined' on Sharepoint choice column

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

I'm querying a SharePoint list with a JavaScript files. Everything is returning fine except the query on a choice column called Devicetype which is coming back undefined and I can't see why. Any thoughts? JS below:

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtName = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
var imgDevicePicture = "";
var tempLCS2 = "";
var HTML = "<h3>Desktop</h3>";
var Laptop = "Y"
var Tabs="Y" ;  
 var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
 var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var NameofDevice = item.Title;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.DevicetypeValue;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;
        var DeviceImage = item.DeviceImage;

        txtTitle = "<p>";  
        txtName = "<p>" + NameofDevice + "</p>"; +  DeviceKind + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
        imgDevicePicture = "<img src='" + DeviceImage + "'>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('devicename').append(txtName);
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
    $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/sites/IT/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");
    $('.deviceimage').append(imgDevicePicture); 

});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

getDevices file

```
function getDevices() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtDeviceType = "";

var query = "http://collaboration.norgine.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?select=ID,Title";
var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });


call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {

        var tempID = result.Id;
        var tempTitle = result.Title;
        var tempDeviceType = result.DeviceTypeValue;
        txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";



    });
    $('#devices').append($(txtTitle));
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the field in the URL:

```
var query = "http://collaboration.norgine.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?select=ID,Title,DeviceTypeValue";
```

Comment: Cheers, I added that @user1t77 but still came back undefined

Comment: Did you specify the correct internal field name? If you're not sure you could check the list definition XML by opening this URL in the browser: `http://collaboration.norgine.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_api/web/list/getbytitle('Devices')`. Or check a specific item configuration: `http://collaboration.norgine.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_api/web/list/getbytitle('Devices')/items(<ITEM_ID>)

Comment: when I paste that URL I get a 404. I'd be happy just to have the 'undefined' not show but when I comment out the    txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle + "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>";

Comment: when I comment out "</a> - " + tempDeviceType + "</p>"; from the url the getDevice function doesn't load

Comment: Try: `txtTitle = txtTitle + "<p><a href='/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalogue%20Devices.aspx?did=" + tempID + "'>" + tempTitle +  "</a></p>"`

Comment: Cheers, that takes out the undefined, but then when I click on link I'm getting 404 it can't find the page?

Comment: Really hard without knowing your environment maybe you have to use an absolute server url like `http://collaboration.norgine.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/SitePages/Service%20Catalog‌​ue%20Devices.aspx...`